# DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE not working in H2

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I want to use H2 with boot when my application close data is lost.I want to save db after application closed.

My application.properties file

```
spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS                    
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test; 
DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password =
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

My test case -

```
HotelEntity hotelEntity = new HotelEntity(1, "Name", "Password", "MobileNumber", "email");
    hotelDao.save(hotelEntity);
    System.out.println("Hotel Dao--");
    List<HotelEntity> hotelEntities = hotelDao.findAll();
    System.out.println(hotelEntities.size());
```

It print the list size is 1 but when i run test case again like this

```
List<HotelEntity> hotelEntities = hotelDao.findAll();
System.out.println(hotelEntities.size());
```

It print the list size is 0